# Integrating joint density

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

If there is a joint density function $f(x,y)=c\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ with $x^2+y^2\leq1$, and I want to find the constant $c$, how would I do that?

My idea was to integrate over $x$ and $y$ and set this all equal to 1, because the PDF should integrate to 1. Here's how I tried to do it:

$$f(x,y)=c\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$
$$1=c\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\,\,dxdy$$
$$1=c\int_0^1 [\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}]_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,\,dy$$

But when I try to evaluate the expression in the brackets, I get $[\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-(1-y^2)-y^2}}-0]$, and this fraction has zero in the denominator. Am I approaching this in the right way? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My idea was to integrate over x and y and set this all equal to 1, because the PDF should integrate to 1

The idea is correct but your bounds are not.

The given support

$$\Omega=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\}$$

is equivalent to this one

$$\Omega=\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: -1\le x\le1;-\sqrt{1-x^2}\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2} \right\}$$

In other words, your pdf is defined over the unit disk.

To integrate your pdf I think it is easier to pass in polars.

$$\int_0^1\rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2}d \rho\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=\frac{2}{3}\pi=1/c$$

thus

$$c=\frac{3}{2\pi}$$

Comment: Polar coordinates makes it a lot easier. Thanks!